# Why does my dojo xhrPost request's response always end up in error handler?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

My javascript:

```
var params = {};
params.selectedCurrency = 'USD';
params.orderIdForTax = '500001';
var xhrArgs1 = {
                 url : 'UpdateCurrencyCmd',
                 handleAs : 'text',
                 content : params,
                 preventCache:false,
                 load:function(data){
                    alert('success!');
                 },
                 error: function(error){
                    alert(error);
                    //the alert says 'SyntaxError: syntax error'

                 },
                 timeout:100000
                };
    dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs1);
```

I tried debugging with firebug, i do get the appropriate response (i think). Here it is;

```
/*
{
    "orderIdForTax": ["500001"],
    "selectedCurrency": ["USD"]
}
*/
```

The comments /* and */ are somehow embedded automatically cuz the url im hitting with xhrPost is actually a command class on ibm's websphere commerce environment. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

**Server code**

```
public void performExecute() throws ECException {

try{
    super.performExecute();
    double taxTotal;
    System.out.println("Updating currency in UpdateCurrencyCmd...");
    GlobalizationContext cntxt = (GlobalizationContext) getCommandContext().getContext(GlobalizationContext.CONTEXT_NAME);
    if(requestProperties.containsKey("selectedCurrency"))
        selectedCurrency =  requestProperties.getString("selectedCurrency");
    else
        selectedCurrency = cntxt.getCurrency();

    if(requestProperties.containsKey("orderIdForTax"))
        orderId = requestProperties.getString("orderIdForTax");

    OrderAccessBean orderBean = new OrderAccessBean();
    cntxt.setCurrency(selectedCurrency.toUpperCase());
    orderBean.setInitKey_orderId(orderId);
    orderBean.refreshCopyHelper();
    orderBean.setCurrency(selectedCurrency.toUpperCase());
    orderBean.commitCopyHelper();

    TypedProperty rspProp = new TypedProperty(); 
    rspProp.put(ECConstants.EC_VIEWTASKNAME, "AjaxActionResponse");
    setResponseProperties(rspProp);


}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage() );
}
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error must be somewhere else. When executing the same code on JSFiddle, I'm getting the "success!" alert. Can you show me your complete code and telle me what version of Dojo you are using?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the server output stream? In the server code sample there are a couple lines of `System.out.println`. Maybe they can help you get a better picture of the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my client side code, weirdly.

```
load:function(data){
    data = data.replace("/*", "");
    data = data.replace("*/", "");  

    var obj = eval('(' + data + ')');
    alert('Success');

}
```

Its weird but this worked. Lol.

Comment: There must have been something else that's wrong... . Replacing a simple `alert()` with this can't be the solution. By the way, this code example has a vulnerability. Don't use `eval()` to translate JSON to an object.

Answer (score 0):

I guess  the problem is with coment-filtering option of  handle as method.
The response should be comment filered as below.
See tha AjaxActionResponse.jsp (WCS)

vailable Handlers

There are several pre-defined contentHandlers available to use. The value represents the key in the handlers map.

```
text (default) - Simply returns the response text
json - Converts response text into a JSON object
xml - Returns a XML document
javascript - Evaluates the response text
json-comment-filtered - A (arguably unsafe) handler to preventing JavaScript hijacking
json-comment-optional - A handler which detects the presence of a filtered response and toggles between json or json-comment-filtered appropriately.
```

Examples